# How to make video responsive in full height on mobile?

Tags: css, vimeo

I have a problem I don´t find the way to solve it.
I´m trying to make a background video to be responsive, so it looks full height on mobile, and it´s almost done, but it shows two borders on top and bottom and I don´t find how to solve it. The video is loaded from Vimeo.

Could anyone please help me?? It´s a problem with css

And this is the css code I´m using :

.fluid-width-video-wrapper {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: 0 !important;
   left: 0 !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 100% !important;
   z-index: -1 !important;
   pointer-events: none !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;

}
.fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe {
   width: 100vw !important;
   height: 56.25vw !important; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 9/16*100 = 56.25 */
   min-height: 100vh !important;
   min-width: 177.77vh !important; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 16/9*100 = 177.77 */
    overflow: hidden !important;
   position: absolute !important;
   top: 50% !important;
   left: 50% !important;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

Please help !! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: When you say mobile do you mean iOS Safari, or Android Chrome, or both? I don't understand what you're trying to do with height < min-height and width < min-width though.

Comment: Already solved, thanks